# Posting a Solution of a problem that You faced to Help Newbies

Tags: discussion

About an Hour ago, I faced a problem and tried different ways to solve it.  At last I was going to post my Question on Stack Overflow, but the last trick which came in my mind worked, and the problem got resolved.

Now, if I want to post that problem on Stack Overflow with the solution which worked for me, for the purpose to help other newbies to get their answer if they face the same problem, what is the proper way of posting such solution to a problem?

Comment: If the question is not a duplicate, then there is no harm in posting the question and then your solution.  Self-answered questions are allowed on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can answer your own question by clicking the "**answer your question**" button toward the end of the page. Answer it as you would someone else's question.

Comment: Thanks , I Know that , But i thought that may be there could be specific area for Problems Which  you have Solved, Thanks

Comment: Nope, there isn't. You just answer your own question.